# Azure - Web App - Mysterious message as response

Tags: c#, azure, encoding, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

## Introduction

I am using **.NET Core 2.1** with a **Web API** which is hosted on **Azure** as an **App Service**.

**UserService** :     `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0" />`
**Service 1** :     `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.2" />`

The **Service 1** is basically calling the **UserService** via a synchronous http call.

For my `HttpClient`I've implemented a very straight forward wrapper class  which you can see here (only the relevant GET implementation):

## Service 1

```
    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string relativeUri, string accessToken)
    {
        var result = default(T);

        try
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = CreateHttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, relativeUri, accessToken);

            // SendAsync is supposed to be thread safe
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // TODO : Only for debugging purposes
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _customHttpClientLogger.LogInformation(content);

            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)))
                {
                    result = _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);

                    _customHttpClientLogger.LogInformation("HTTP GET to {url} was successful.", relativeUri);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _customHttpClientLogger.LogError(ex, "HTTP GET to {url} received an error.", relativeUri);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private HttpRequestMessage CreateHttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod httpMethod, string relativeUri, string accessToken, string authenticationSchema = BEARER)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(relativeUri, UriKind.Relative),
            Method = httpMethod,
        };

        // Has to be added on a per-request basis, otherwise it would be shared with other requests.
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"{authenticationSchema} {accessToken}");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        return request;
    }
```

### HttpClient Registration

```
            services.AddHttpClient<UserServiceHttpClient>()
                .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(c => new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseProxy = false,
                    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
                })
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler>();
```

## Service 2 (UserService)

```
    [HttpGet("api/user")]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(List<User>), Description = "A list of user entities.")]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Description = "An error occured.")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var users = await _userService.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(users);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _userControllerLogger.LogError(ex.InnerException ?? ex,
                "An error occcured in the method {method}() in the class '{class}'.", nameof(GetAllAsync), nameof(UserController));
        }

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
```

## Issue

Everything here works perfectly well on my **localhost** environment and the request is being processed by **Service 1**. Unfortunately, once I host this on Azure, the call to the api `/api/user` returns something like the following as `HttpContent`.

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
_customHttpClientLogger.LogInformation(content);
```

?      ?`I?%&/m?{J?J??t??`$?@??????iG#)?*??eVe]f@????{???{???;?N'????\fdl??J??!????~|?"????*f=?}?n??E???z??<[6?u?????O?j?U?v:/??v?v???????????[????????EV??Y?7?G???}??9}?i?:?[?????q??`??X?T3??????E{MIg??h?????O??_]L????>Z??yQ?g??^dm???IQ]??j`gi?

The funny thing is, that if I call the **UserService** (`/api/user`) directly via **Postman**, then I do receive a proper `json`response. I also made sure that I use the exact same `HttpHeaders` as in the code.

[image]

[image]

## Execution Paths

**Localhost:**

- Postman => UserService (api/user) => **(works)**
- Postman => Service 1 UserService (api/user) => **(works)**
- WebApplication => Service1 => UserService (api/user) => **(works)**

**Azure:**

- Postman => UserService (api/user) => **(works)**
- Postman => Service 1 => UserService (api/user) => **(doesnt work)**
- WebApplication => Service1 => UserService (api/user) => **(doesnt work)**

## Summary

No matter which execution path you take (also the one which dont work), the user service is **always** called and returns a **successful** response. I could verify via remote debugging that the user service was always returning a `OK()` response.

I am really struggeling to find out where the part with the encoding could have gone wrong.

The **UserService** in **Azure** seems to work without any troubles but as soon as I call it from **Service 1** it seem to not work anymore.

Could it be that some `HttpMessageHandler` or `Middleware`is interfering with the request?

As strange as it sounds, this issue **only** appears once it's hosted in **Azure**.

Are there any Azure specific outbound rules or interceptors which could tamper with my request?

Here are the **NuGet packages** which I am using for **Service 1**:

```
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="2.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="2.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.7.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="4.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

I would be very grateful for everything which could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like in some use cases the content is gzipped while in other ones - not. Try to disable gzip encoding and check whether you have the same weird behaviour. If not, that means you've missed something related to it.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why my middleware from `Service1` wouldn't decompress the gzipped content? The next thing I will be checking is if the `Content-Encoding` header is set on the response from the `UserService`. I really hope Azure isn't stripping that away ...

Comment: This is how the response looks like if I call it from postman https://i.imgur.com/x3oy7C3.png, compared to the one from Service1 https://i.imgur.com/lsqou3h.png. `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding` are both not set ..

Comment: Content encoding is gzip try to decompress data before use

Comment: The middleware should be taking care of that but of course with the missing `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding` header it won't be activated. Any ideas why those http headers are missing once I do interservice communication in Azure? Once again, this works beautifully on my localhost environment. Is there a header whitelisting for interservice communication within Azure?